# Possible to use Chef variables within Inspec?

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I'm learning to write integration tests for my Chef cookbooks. Is it possible to reference variables from the `attributes` folder within my test?

Here's my test to make sure `httpd` and `php` are installed properly. However, I have additional packages I want to check for.

## test/smoke/default/install.rb

```
%w(httpd php).each do |rpm_package|
  describe package(rpm_package) do
    it { should be_installed }
  end
end
```

## attributes/default.rb

```
default['ic_apachephp']['php_packages'] = [
                              'php-mysqlnd',
                              'php-mbstring',
                              'php-gd',
                              'php-xml',
                              'php'
                            ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, however not "directly". Matt Wrock described it in this [blog entry](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/accessing-chef-node-attributes-from-kitchen-tests).

Necessary steps are:

- add a cookbook (e.g. called `export-node`, below `test/fixtures/cookbooks/`) that includes a recipe with the following content (dumping node attributes into the specified JSON file):

  ```rb
  ruby_block "Save node attributes" do
    block do
      IO.write("/tmp/kitchen_chef_node.json", node.to_json)
    end
  end
  ```
- add this recipe to the the run list in `.kitchen.yml`
- load the `node` object in your inspec test using

  ```rb
  node = json('/tmp/kitchen_chef_node.json').params
  ```

Beware that you manually have to pick from the right attribute precedence level (automatic/default/normal/override), as those are not merged.

You can find an example of mine also in this cookbook: [TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-pdns](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-pdns).

EDIT: I forgot the step to tell Berkshelf about that cookbook. Add to your `Berksfile`:

```rb
group :integration do
  cookbook 'export-node', path: 'test/fixtures/cookbooks/export-node'
end
```

Comment: All right, so ... in order to add the cookbook to the `run_list` within `.kitchen.yml`, I had to add `depends export-node` in the cookbook I'm testing. is that right? Without the `depends` clause, it keeps telling me that the `export-node` cookbook can't be found.Once I got past that, I'm greeted with `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/kitchen/chef_node.json` ... except the file is on the docker container.

Comment: No need to add the dependency (you don't want that cookbook on your production nodes, don't you?). It will be automatically found when it's in `test/fixtures/cookbooks`. Please have a look at the cookbook I've referenced.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the berkshelf part. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, after hours of banging my head, it was the `Berksfile` i was missing. :) ... all good it works now!

Comment: Just curious, but is there a way to have the `export-node` cookbook available to all cookbooks? If I have twenty cookbooks I want to test, i would need said cookbook under each test folder, no?

Comment: Sure, it just needs to be resolvable by Berkshelf. Actually, this is a pretty good idea. It could even be in the supermarket. Alternatively, anywhere from where Berkshelf can fetch it, e.g. `../node-exporter` or a git repo.

Comment: I feel stupid after adding such code to 5 of my cookbooks ^^

Comment: Damn it, there you go [node-exporter](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/export-node) by mwrock. I misunderstood the blog article.

Comment: @luckytaxi  I am still having issues with the No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/kitchen/chef_node.json even though the file exists im the container. I've checked all comments and everything seems to be up to date but still it throws the message. Did the Berksfile really fix that issue for you?